# How to exclude certain values from randomly generated array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have written a function which generates an array with 10 randomly generated unique Values.

I would like to extend it such that certain values are not included.

This is my code:

```
let excludedValues = [20,32,40,46,64,66,14,30,34];
let randomArray = [];

  while(randomArray.length < 10){
    let randomValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

    let valueNotAllowed = excludedValues.includes(randomValue);
    while (valueNotAllowed) {
      randomValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      valueNotAllowed = excludedValues.includes(randomValue);
    }

    if(randomArray.indexOf(randomValue) === -1) randomArray.push(randomValue);
}
console.log(randomArray);
```

It creates an array of length 10 with unique values between 1 and 100 but ii still includes the values in the `excludedValues` Array

How can I get it to work that those values do not end up in the array

Thanks in advance

Comment: The code seems to work. Are you sure the excluded values get added?

Answer (score 3):

You could take a single loop and omit code repetition.

```js
const excludedValues = [20, 32, 40, 46, 64, 66, 14, 30, 34],
    randomArray = [];

while (randomArray.length < 10) {
  const randomValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

  if (excludedValues.includes(randomValue) || randomArray.includes(randomValue)) continue;
  randomArray.push(randomValue);
}

console.log(...randomArray);
```

Taking the set idea a bit ahead ...

```js
const
    getRandom = (limit, excludes = []) => {
        const values = new Set(excludes);
        limit += excludes.length;
        while (values.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1).size < limit) ;
        return Array.from(values).slice(excludes.length);
    };

console.log(...getRandom(10, [20, 32, 40, 46, 64, 66, 14, 30, 34]));
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to already posted answer you can use of `Set`

```js
function getUniqueRandomValues(exclusion = []) {
  // By definition, values inside of a Set are unique
  const randomArray = new Set();

  do {
    const randomValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

    // If the exclusion rule is satisfied push the new value in the random array
    if (!exclusion.length || !exclusion.includes(randomValue)) {
      randomArray.add(randomValue);
    }
  } while (randomArray.size < 10);

  return Array.from(randomArray);
}

console.log(getUniqueRandomValues([20, 32, 40, 46, 64, 66, 14, 30, 34]));
```

Comment: nice idea with set. i took it for a shorter approach by taking exclusion array as start values for the set. this need to remove the first items of the set later.

Answer (score 0):

No need for an inner `while` loop. If the `randomValue` is in the excluded list or is  already in the array, just continue. Eventually the original `while` will complete.

```js
let excludedValues = [20, 32, 40, 46, 64, 66, 14, 30, 34];
let randomArray = [];

while (randomArray.length < 10) {
  let randomValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  if(
    false === excludedValues.includes(randomValue) &&
    -1 === randomArray.indexOf(randomValue)
  ) {
    randomArray.push(randomValue);
  }
}
console.log(randomArray);
```